# Why the loader not display proper in IE browser?

Tags: html, css, svg, loader

I am developing a web application in which **I am using an SVG as a loader**.

*SVG is working fine in Google Chrome, Edge browser* but **not proper in the Internet Explorer browser**.

Image of *Chrome and Edge browser*:

[image]

Image of Loader in *Internet exproer browser*:

[image]

Code:

```
 <div id="loadingSVG" style="text-align: center; padding-top: 20%;">
    <svg style="height:155px;width:155px;">
        <use xlink:href="#umbrellaSVG" width="115px" height="115px"></use>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Image with Inspect Element:

[image]

Comment: I have also same issue

Answer (score 1):

Can you try use svg like as `<img src="https://link-to-your-svg-loader.svg" />` ?

Comment: SVG is created by me so I dont have live path

Comment: Try upload your svg to your folders and try using this code. Internet explorer can't rendering svg for security.

https://caniuse.com/#search=svg 

"IE9-Edge12, Safari 5.1-6, and UCWeb 11 do not support referencing external files via <use xlink:href>. Polyfills are available: server-side inlining + snippet - script"

Comment: My loader cuts from all the edges

Comment: I have got an a new idea. Can you use it on css file like as background? add your svg file to css as background. eg: `.loader {background:url(your-svg-file.svg) no-repeat;}`

Comment: I make svg with path not .svg file I write like   `<svg style="height:155px;width:155px;">
        <use xlink:href="#umbrellaSVG" width="115px" height="115px"></use>
    </svg>`

Comment: i voted your answer if u like the question then vote. thanks